# Angular font awesome icon as content in css renders as box

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, angular-ngselect

I have gone through multiple resources before posting this question here. I am using an angular project where I am trying to use ng-select and replace the dropdown icon with something else from font-awesome.

I have added font-awesome to the project using the below 2 steps:

```
ng add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

Trying to replace the **ng-select** dropdown icon in the css using below:

```
.ng-select ::ng-deep .ng-arrow-wrapper .ng-arrow {
  display: none;
}

.ng-select ::ng-deep span.ng-arrow-wrapper::before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f078';
}
```

It's rendered as below

[image]

Any inputs are appreciated. Here is the stackblitz url that I am trying : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrhnot?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of adding font awesome icons using CSS content property.

```css
.icon::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }

  .login::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900; content: "\f007";
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul style="margin: 0;">
  <li><span class="icon login"></span> <- Login Icon</li>
</ul>
```

Make sure you have followed this pattern and check for the correct Unicode codepoints you are including in `content`

Comment: This solved my issue where I needed to add the icon from its unicode in the content property (Angular 12). Thanks!